# ? Operator using MVC Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, operators

```
<span>@Model.SelectedOrderTypeName  @Model.Percentage ? @Model.FinancialSupportPercentage % : @Model.Amount $</span>
```

How do I do the above in Razor syntax? (Basically if Percentage is not null display it otherwise display amount

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets

```
<span>@Model.SelectedOrderTypeName  @(Model.Percentage != null ? Model.FinancialSupportPercentage + "%" : Model.Amount + "$")</span>
```

Without the brackets, every time you use `@` you are returning something, meaning you will likely be displaying a  `<span>` containing `@Model.SelectedOrderTypeName`'s value,  `@Model.Percentage`'s, value a `?` literal character,  `@Model.FinancialSupportPercentage`'s value, a `%` literal character, `:`, `@Model.Amount`'s value and finally a `$` literal.

Adding brackets turns this into one return - allowing ternary functions to be written.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<span>@Model.SelectedOrderTypeName  (Model.Percentage? Model.FinancialSupportPercentage + "%" : Model.Amount + "$")</span>`